# Can I switch perspective in Eclipse by clicking an icon?

Tags: eclipse

I switch between two perspective in Eclipse 3.4.2 is there any chance I can do that via icon = one click only?

I run Eclipse inside Virtual Box on Windows XP and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> doesn't work for me. I want to use mouse anyway.

Comment: The icons in the upper right are perspectives.

Comment: You mean clicking the same icon takes you there *and* back again at the same time?

Comment: I am happy with @JB's answer. Works nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. They are in the top right corner :

[image]

Comment: I saw that but didn't know I am able to customize that.